# Win32: What should unneeded handles be set to in STARTUPINFO when STARTF_USESTDHANDLES used?

Tags: winapi

The docs for [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure offers the flag `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` but it doesn't say what to set the handles to when not needed.

In other words, say you only need `.hStdOutput`, what should `.hStdInput` and `.hStdError` be set to, `0` or `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` or is it required to pass all three?

Thanks.

Comment: no big different. can use any value. most logical use 0

Comment: When the docs say "*otherwise, this member is ignored*" it means just that - whatever value happens to be in that member is ignored. You can set it to NULL, or leave it uninitialized or assign it a random value for all Windows cares.

Comment: @dxiv - *otherwise, this member is ignored* related to case when no flag `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` but in case flag `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` is set in *dwFlags* - really nothing in msdn about stdhandle value

Comment: @RbMm Right, thank you for the correction. Also, I just noticed this part "*if this flag [`STARTF_USESTDHANDLES`] is specified when calling the `GetStartupInfo` function, these members are either the handle value specified during process creation or `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`*". While this is not directly related to OP's question, it suggests that `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is recognized as well in the context of `STARTUPINFO`.

Comment: @dxiv - really this is direct related to question.  `GetStartupInfo` return values as is. this is hint that in case some `hStd*` unused - set it value to `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`

Comment: also from [`GetStdHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle) - *If the function fails, the return value is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.* "fail" this api only in case value of *nStdHandle* is `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`

Answer (score -1):

Any value you wanted can be used only if you know what are you doing. But as @RbMm said, most logical use 0 for unneeded standard handles.